# how to update crontab without using crontab -e

Tags: cron

I want to update my user crontab from a java program. That is, I want to load the existing cron file, delete any obsolete lines, add new lines and then save the new file.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this. The actual cron file is in /var/spool/cron (centos) but there are warnings not to modify this file. crontab -e doesn't help unless I write a custom editor to do the file swap or a complicated shell script to pipe in the new lines after deleting the old file.

So, is there a simple way to write out a cron file and then install it?

Comment: Are you using a Centos version with Systemd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `crontab` without any options installs a crontab from `stdin`.

`crontab -l` returns the current crontab if you need to append to the old crontab.

Comment: Thanks. The man page notes this in the synopsis but not in the description of the command. Guess I needed to RTFM better.